# Search design issue

Tags: xml

I am designing Search component,before i implement i need few suggestions from experts.

160.000 records in db ,based on id i have to retrieve the results. So here I have two options.

1. based on id,i will go database and retrieve the results.
2. created one cache object using ehcache and perform search on that element.

can any one suggest me good approach.

Regards,
RK

Comment: Why is this tagged with XML? Where is XML involved in this question?

Answer (score 0):

It would generally be best to search against the database. If the performance (speed not memory) was not good enough with this solution, you might look to pre load a cache and do a lookup there. More often than not, looking up the database would be best.

Of course this can depend on how much data you a returning and the size of the data being returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold the entire db in memory, you'll have to replicate the capabilities of the db like indexing, query plans, sorting, etc. You're far better off beefing up the hardware capabilities of the server, like going with solid state memory, for example.